# Generating rails model for dropped migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I had a model customer, which I have generated using the following

> rails g model Customer name:string

After some time, I decided to rename the model to customer_type, to accomplish this we wrote an another migration

> rails g migration RenameCutomerToCustomerType

everything was smooth until I had the requirement to add the model named customer. When I issued the following command, I've started getting **"Another migration is already named create_customer"**

> rails g model Customer

I think this kind of scenario is very common in CRUD based project, please suggest on how to over come this? Is this a limitation with rails?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just rename old migration filename and classname. Both don't affect anything.

btw: This scenario is quite rare so I don't think that there is any need in specific actions from framework

Comment: Also you can safely remove old migration if you keep schema.rb under vcs as recommended

Comment: I recommend renaming old migration to `create_customer_1.rb` and class to `CreateCustomer1`. When you encounter this issue second time on the same model, use `create_customer_2.rb` instead and so on...

Comment: I had the same issue and renamed my old model from `CreateCar` to `CreateCar2015` and the file to `create_car_2015` since it was made in 2015. It only checks the class/file names, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

rails destroy model MODELNAME, will remove the model.

Comment: This doesn't work, because the migration conflict just checks for the existence of the initial creation based on class name, and not whether it was dropped. The specific conflict is over the create_model.rb file generated